# When using the Linq methods .Any(<predicate>) and .All(<predicate>) on an IList, are the predicates applied to the list in a strict sequence?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class `SomeObject` which has a function `Evaluate()` which returns a bool. If I had an `IList<SomeObject>` like this:

```
IList<SomeObject> parameters;
parameters.Add( objA );
parameters.Add( objC );
parameters.Add( objB );
```

And I apply a Linq expression like `Any` or `All`

```
var res = parameters.Any( p => p.Evaluate() );
```

what order would the predicate `p.Evaluate()` be evaluated in? Would it be

- `objA` then `objB` then `objC` (assuming the `SomeObject` is sortable and `objA` < `objB` < `objC`)
- `objA` then `objC` then `objB` (the order they were `Add`ed to the `IList<>`)

Or is the order of evaluation not something that can be relied upon?

Comment: What makes you believe it would spend the extra CPU cycles performing a sort before it did the Any when doing the sort would provide 0 bonus to the evaluation?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Could be an IList implementation that's always sorted.

Comment: Your code doesnt work because you haven't initialized the list. It could make a difference what class you use to initialize it. While `List<T>` always enumerates in the order of the indexes you could write a class that implements `IList<T>` that uses a different order, f.e. `ReverseList<T>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are correct, I haven't. In the specific instance the `parameters` object is a parameter into a function. Assume it is a `List<SomeObject>`, although it could be anything that implements `IList`

Comment: One point worth mentioning: you shouldn't want to care unless the predicates you're passing to `.Any()` or `.All()` have observable side effects, which is a Bad Idea. If they *do* have side effects, rather than relying on any particular order that `.Any()` or `.All()` should have according to you, you're better off looping explicitly in an imperative fashion, rather than pretending you're doing functional style programming.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is exactly the point. The predicates **have** side effects. The issue is that the code that was here previously was a `for` loop, but it has been changed to a `.Any()` and my worry was it would _look_ like it was evaluating the predicates in index order, but then when we weren't looking it would evaluate them in a different order and we'd all be scratching our heads wondering what happened.

Comment: Well, here's a far better reason than hypothetical `ReverseList`s to worry about predicates with side effects: you can no longer slip in an `.AsParallel()` to smoothly speed up queries by using PLINQ. (To be fair, this is also true if there are *non* observable side effects, since private data will not be magically locked -- predicates with no side effects whatsoever are just a good thing to have.)

Comment: To put it another way: your code as written now won't suddenly break (or at least, the possibility of this happening is small enough that it shouldn't be a concern), but the style is still questionable because it invites changes that *will* break it. Personally, I'd try very hard to rewrite the side-effect producing methods to *not* have side effects (for example, by doing all the updates up front, storing the results and and then not caring about the order anymore), or else I'd switch to an explicit loop, with a comment to maintainers that the order matters if that isn't obvious.

Answer (score 5):

LINQ operates on `IEnumerable<T>` instances, so the order in which operations are applied is pretty much the order the underlying enumerator returns them, by definition.

However, [`IList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=netframework-4.7) does not have any guarantee in which order items are enumerated. In the vast majority of cases (and probably for all framework implementations of `IList<T>`) it will be the index order of items in the list, but the interface doesn't seem to guarantee that, so an implementation could do whatever it wants.

Comment: You are technically correct, which is the best kind of correct. However, any implementation of `IList<T>` that didn't yield the elements in exactly the order you would get with a simple looping through the indexes would probably be considered broken by clients, even if Microsoft forgot to write this down explicitly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: that's not true, why is my `ReverseList<T>` class broken?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: `ReverseList<T>` would probably reverse the index access, too, though.

Comment: @Joey: exactly, so it works as intended but it doesnt yield the items in the order they were added. I could also implement a `RandomOrderList<T>`.

Comment: @Tim: But it does yield them in index order (which is what Jeroen mentioned).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I think my use of "probably" allows me to wave away any "but my implementation is being deliberately creative and beloved by its clients for that" objections of this kind. But if not, I've still made my point. More power to you and your freaky lists.